# Wrapping sprintf to not throw errors at compile time but at runtime?

Tags: f#

Let's say I wanted to have an alias of `sprintf`, I would simply do this:

```
namespace FSharp

module Core =
    let specialsprintf x y =
        sprintf x y
```

This would bring me the same compilation-time advantages (compared to its C# cousin API `System.String.Format`) of sprintf such as type-checking, checking number of parameters passed is correct, etc.

However, let's say I wanted to disable this compilation-time niceties and write a simple version of sprintf by calling String.Format underneath. Could this be possible? I know the goal sounds stupid but I want to do this mental exercise to make sure I understand how F# typing works here. If I do this (supposing we only can pass one parameter):

```
namespace FSharp

module Core =
    let specialsprintf x y =
#if NORMAL_FSHARP
        sprintf x y
#else
        let x = x.Replace("%s", "{0}")
        System.String.Format(x,y)
#endif
```

It doesn't even compile, the error is:

```
~/FSharpPlayground.fs(17,17): Error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved. (FS0072) (FSharpPlayground)
```

Mmmm why?

Ok, if I specify the type like this:

```
namespace FSharp

module Core =
    let specialsprintf
#if NORMAL_FSHARP
        x
#else
        (x: string)
#endif
        y =
#if NORMAL_FSHARP
            sprintf x y
#else
            let x = x.Replace("%s", "{0}")
            System.String.Format(x,y)
#endif
```

Then I end up with a compilation error in the caller:

```
~/FSharpPlaygroundUse.fs(48,48): Error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type 'obj []' but here has type 'string' (FS0001)
```

I guess I need now to qualify the type of `y` now, but not sure how to do it in case I wanted to extend it to be able to use 2 arguments instead of just 1 (I don't manage to make it work with the `ParamArray` attribute). Something tells me that I probably also need an `uncurry` function but I'm a bit lost :-/

Comment: It fails because the second argument in String.Format is an object array. Use `[| y |]` instead.

Comment: If you do this `#if NORMAL_FSHARP
        x
#else
        (x: string)
#endif` and pass in something other than a string, then `x.Replace("%s", "{0}")` will fail so I'm not sure I understand what the aim is. Are you trying to trick the compiler into thinking something is type safe when it's not?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that what you want is something like `sprintf` but variadic, and without type checking the format.

There's no 'uncurrying' or variable argument functions for F#, unfortunately. 
That being said, there's the option of using a parameter array. `ParamArray` is only valid on class members not bindings, so we can settle for a `static member` which is similar in scope to a `let fn () =`.

```
type SpecialPrint =
    static member sprintf (format, [<ParamArray>] args) =
        let index = ref -1        
        let stringFormat = Regex.Replace(format, "%[a-z]", (fun _ -> sprintf "{%d}" (Interlocked.Increment index)))
        String.Format(stringFormat, args)
```

With;

```
let result = SpecialPrint.sprintf ("Hello %s%s", "World", "!") //Hello World!
```

Comment: P.S. Interlocked is overkill, but hey.

Comment: but with this I would need to change all my current uses of sprintf to use uncurried arguments, instead of a simple sprintf->specialsprintf search&replace :(

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what you want.

Comment: Do you only want `specialsprintf ` to only work with a single parameter?

Comment: I want currified arguments for specialsprintf , but in the same way sprintf can accept variable number of arguments, I want the same for specialsprintf

Comment: `printf` is special - the compiler rewrites your format string into a `PrintFormat<>`, F# does not support a variable number of arguments.